# error: no type named 'extents' in namespace 'boost'

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use the boost multi_array, it works in my main driver code, however when I try to use it in a header file of mine it gives me the following error:

`error: no type named 'extents' in namespace 'boost'`

**main.cpp**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::multi_array<double, 3> A(boost::extents[2][2][2]);

  return 0;
}
```

the following works

```
c++ -I /usr/local/include/ main.cpp
./a.out
```

however, using a header file doesn't.

*my_header.hpp*

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

my_class
{
private:
  boost::multi_array<double, 3> A(boost::extents[2][2][2]);
public:
  my_class();
};
```

*my_header.cpp*

```
#include "my_header.hpp"

#include <iostream>

my_class::my_class()
{
  std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
}
```

i.e.

`c++ -I /usr/local/include/ -c my_header.cpp`

gives:

`./my_header.hpp:6:42: error: no type named 'extents' in namespace 'boost'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is confusing but really your syntax is incorrect. Try this

```
class my_class
{
private:
    boost::multi_array<double, 3> A;
public:
    my_class() : A(boost::extents[2][2][2]) {}
};
```